# One to many, one view do I need a custom model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a database base first application so I have no homemade modals as such, just the ones created automatically. I want to display in a single view the one and many parts from a select in single row in an html table/list, here is the SQL that works great in a re-created MS Access Query, - some brackets:

```
SELECT Facilitiy.FacilityName, Facilitiy.FacilityImage, FacilityDetail.FacilityDetailDescription
FROM FacilityDetail INNER JOIN Facilitiy ON FacilityDetail.FacilityDetailID = Facilitiy.FacilityFK
WHERE FacilityFK = id
```

And the LINQ that gives me the correct many part of the list:

```
from fd in db.FacilityDetails
join f in db.Facilities on fd.FacilityID equals f.FacilityFK
where f.B FacilityFK == id
select f
```

I had kind of hoped that would do it as the SQL does but I need to create a modal that I can put in a view to display:

**FacilityImage(one side) | FacilityName(one side) | FacilityDetailDescription(many side)**

I have heard I can simply do it by doing something like this???

```
from fd in db.FacilityDetails.Include("Facilities")
```

but it seems to make no difference!

Which leads me to believe I need to create a new custom model? If so how would i write it?

I tried something like this but I cant get it to work.

```
public class FacilitiyDetails
{
    public string FacilitiesDescription { get; set; }
    public string FacilitiesImage { get; set; }
    public string BeachFacilitiesDescription { get; set; }
{
```

I'm not quite sure what i'm supposed to do here!

Comment: Can you show us your Entity Model?

Comment: There is not much to see, it's just two database tables, one with all the available "Facilities" and a middle table with all the Facilities that relate to “id” from the main table. One id has many FacilityDeatails, and one Facility has many FacilityDeatails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need a custom model because you're wanting to display multiple types. You'll need to have something like:

```
public class FacilityModel
{
    public Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public List<FacilityDetails> FacilityDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Based on your class above and assuming you have a Facility class already. Then you'll need to change your LINQ to first get the Facility details:

```
var facility = (from f in db.Facilities
                 where f.FacilityID == id
                 select f)
               .FirstOrDefault(); //just being safe here, 
                                  //if it's null, you'll want to escape out of
                                  //the code below
```

Then you'll need to get all equivalent `FacilityDetails` for that facility by doing:

```
var facilityDetails = (from fd in db.FacilityDetails
                      where fd.FacilityFK == id
                      select fd).ToList()
```

Then you can create a new instance of your Model by doing:

```
var model = new FacilityModel
            {
                Facility = facility,
                FacilityDetails = facilityDetails
            };
```

Comment: thank you for understanding what I was talking about! I agonized for quite a while about how to ask the question but you hit the hammer right on the head! I was actually closer than I thought I was in the end. Thanks again and thanks for a well written explanation too!

Comment: Hehe no problems, I only know what you mean because I've had those exact same problems at work in the past so I can relate to them! Glad I could help :)